# Design schema to query select beetwen two separate dates

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cql

I have a table for messages, like this:

```
messages (
    user_id uuid,
    id uuid,
    message blob,
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, id)
)
```

I can create a MV for sort and select messages by `updated_at`.  But when I need to select last updated messages from last time when client sync (e.g. `select where updated_at > 1555602962006 and created_at < 1555602962006`) - only way is to select all messages by `updated_at` and filter rows in code? Is this a normal practice in production?

Maybe in this case, it's possible to create some token to sort by concatenating `created_at` and `updated_at` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the tricky part about this, is that Cassandra will not allow a range query on multiple, different columns.  Secondly, range queries only work *within* a partition, so you'll need to come up with a time "bucketing" strategy.

One way that I have modeled around this in the past, was to have one column for a timestamp, but different *rows* for the type of time.  I'll put together an example here, using your table above.  For a time bucket, I'll use month; essentially, I know I'll only ever query for messages created/updated in the last month (that may or may not work for you).

```
CREATE TABLE messages_by_month (
  month_bucket int,
  event_time timestamp,
  user_id uuid,
  id uuid,
  message text,
  event text,
  PRIMARY KEY (month_bucket, event_time, id));
```

After INSERTing some data, I can now query for a range of created and updated event times, like this:

```
SELECT id,event_time,event,message
FROM messages_by_month 
WHERE month_bucket=201905
  AND event_time > 1558619000000
  AND event_time < 1558624900000;

 id                                   | event_time                      | event   | message
--------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+---------
 a4d60c29-ad4e-4023-b869-edf1ea6207e2 | 2019-05-23 14:00:00.000000+0000 | CREATED |     hi!
 66e78a1e-dbcb-4f64-a0aa-6d5b0e64d0ed | 2019-05-23 14:20:00.000000+0000 | CREATED |     hi!
 f1c59bf4-1351-4527-a24b-80bb6e3a2a5c | 2019-05-23 15:00:00.000000+0000 | UPDATED |    hi2!
 a4d60c29-ad4e-4023-b869-edf1ea6207e2 | 2019-05-23 15:20:00.000000+0000 | UPDATED |    hi3!

(4 rows)
```

While this exact example may not work for you, the idea is to think about organizing your data differently to support your query.

Note:  With this example, you'll need to watch your partition sizes.  You may end up having to add another partition key if this table gets more than 50k-100k messages in a month.

Comment: I thought about it, but even if I make the key "day", there can be thousands of updated messages in a single chat, and the client only needs to update the cache already loaded.   
   
I think Cassandra is just not suitable for such cases, but our application uses Cassandra for everything.   
   
Perhaps the correct solution is to use elasticsearch for these purposes or something like that.